# Cannot find 'taskCellVM' in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm following a tutorial to make a reminders app in swiftui. I'm pretty new to more complex apps in swiftui and there were these errors in the debugger. What do they mean and how I can solve them. If it helps, the tutorial that I'm watching is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RUeW5rUcww

Thank you in advance.

```
1)TaskListView.swift:15:25: error: failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report
    var body: some View {

2) TaskListView.swift:20:45: error: cannot find 'taskCellVM' in scope
                    in TaskCell(taskCellVM: taskCellVM)
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

TaskListView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var taskListVM = TaskListViewModel()
    
    let tasks = testDataTasks
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                List(taskListVM.taskCellViewModels){
                    TaskCellVM
                    in TaskCell(taskCellVM: taskCellVM)
                    
                }
                Button(action: {}) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill").resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        Text("Add New Task")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
    }
}

struct TaskListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            TaskListView()
                .previewDevice("iPhone 12 Pro Max")
        }
    }
}

struct TaskCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var taskCellVM: TaskCellViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: taskCellVM.task.completed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" :  "circle").resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            Text(taskCellVM.task.title)
        }
    }
}
```

TaskCellViewModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class TaskCellViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var task: Task
    
    var id = ""
    @Published var completionStateIconName = ""
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        
        $task
            .map{
            task in task.completed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"
        }
        .assign(to: \.completionStateIconName, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $task
            .map { task
                in task.id
            }
            .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

TaskListViewModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class TaskListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var taskCellViewModels = [TaskCellViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        self.taskCellViewModels = testDataTasks.map{
            task in TaskCellViewModel(task: task)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just typo. Using some persistent naming convention (eg. all vars lowercased, all types capitalised, etc) you can avoid such in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                List(taskListVM.taskCellViewModels){
                    TaskCellVM
                    in TaskCell(taskCellVM: taskCellVM)
                    
                }
```

You used `TaskCellVM` as the parameter to the `List`'s closure, but you used `taskCellVM` in the `TaskCell` initializer. Capitalization needs to match.